# SQL Server to display a view to show products at parent and child level

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, hierarchy

### I have a table like this:

```
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| ID |   Name   | Is_Group | Parent_id |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+  
|  1 | Clothes  |        1 | Null      |  
|  2 | Food     |        1 | Null      |  
|  3 | fastfood |        1 | 2         |  
|  4 | T-shirt  |        0 | 1         |
|  5 | skirt    |        0 | 1         |
|  6 | pizza    |        0 | 3         |
|  7 | snack    |        0 | 3         |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
```

I would like to have a horizontal representation to use for reporting such as:

```
+----+---------+---------+----------+
| ID |  Name   | level1  |  level2  |
+----+---------+---------+----------+
|  4 | T-shirt | Clothes | Null     |
|  5 | skirt   | Clothes | Null     |
|  6 | pizza   | Food    | fastfood |
|  7 | snack   | Food    | fastfood |
+----+---------+---------+----------+
```

Would anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use two levels of `left join`:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(tpp.name, tp.name) as level1,
       (case when tpp.name is not null then tp.name end) as level2
from t left join
     t tp
     on t.parent_id = tp.id left join
     t tpp
     on tp.parent_id = tpp.parent_id
where not exists (select 1
                  from t tc
                  where tc.parent_id = t.id);
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. I also use left join the tables but the result was:  


ID -- Name -- level1 -- level2

4 T-shirt Clothes Null

5 skirt Clothes Null

6 pizza fastfood  Food

7 snack fastfood  Food

I want to show that level1 is the highest parent level

Comment: @AnnYoah . . . I modified the answer so the values are in the opposite order.